# fetching data from table (oracle) in servlet and passing to jsp

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, servlets

In my database table name is **abc** and it contains only one row like this:

```
                F         S         T        FO     FI
              10/2=?      2         3        5      1
```

where 1st column name=F,
2nd column name is S, 
3rd column name is T, and so on.

In home.jsp-----------

```
 <form action="NewServlet1" method="post">

Enter Table Name :<input type="text" name="table"> 
                   <input type="submit" value="Display">   
</form>
```

In NewServlet1 doPost---------

```
    String tb=request.getParameter("table");   
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from "+tb);

    while (rs.next()) {

      rs.getString("F");
      rs.getString("S");
      rs.getString("T");
      rs.getString("FO");
      rs.getString("FI"); 
        }
    request.setAttribute("fi", "F");
    request.setAttribute("fi1", "S");
    request.setAttribute("fi2", "T");
    request.setAttribute("fi3", "FO");
    request.setAttribute("fi4", "FI");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

result.jsp-------------------

```
         String abc="", abc1="",abc2="",abc3="",abc4="";
 abc= (String) request.getAttribute("fi");
  abc1= (String) request.getAttribute("fi1");
   abc2= (String) request.getAttribute("fi2");
    abc3= (String) request.getAttribute("fi3");
     abc4= (String) request.getAttribute("fi4");
 out.println(abc);
  out.println(abc1);
   out.println(abc2);
    out.println(abc3);
     out.println(abc4);
```

I should get value in d browser page like this

```
10/2=?
 2
 3
 5
 1
```

But i am getting like this:

```
F S T FO FI
```

Where I am wrong?? thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
while (rs.next()) {

  rs.getString("F");
  rs.getString("S");
  rs.getString("T");
  rs.getString("FO");
  rs.getString("FI"); 
}
```

you are not storing and using values selected form table, but instead you are setting fixed values for your attributes.

```
request.setAttribute("fi", "F");   // fixed string F
request.setAttribute("fi1", "S");  // fixed string S
request.setAttribute("fi2", "T");  // fixed string T
request.setAttribute("fi3", "FO"); // fixed string F0
request.setAttribute("fi4", "FI"); // fixed string FI
```

Instead of above code you can use something like

```
if (rs.next()){ //I used `if` since we expect only one row. 
    request.setAttribute("fi", rs.getString("F"));   
    request.setAttribute("fi1", rs.getString("S"));  
    request.setAttribute("fi2", rs.getString("T"));  
    request.setAttribute("fi3", rs.getString("FO")); 
    request.setAttribute("fi4", rs.getString("FI")); 
}

request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```